# Parse POST data from REQUEST

Tags: c#, json, parsing, post, request

Is there a way to tell if the input was passed as parameters or as an object? If I pass as parameters the data is in the form of `a=1&b=2&c=3` but if I pass a `JSon objec`t as an input it is in the form `{"a" : 1, "b" : 2, "c" : 3 }`

I need to extract the value of `c` from the inputs being passed. So for my parsing routine how do I tell the form it is in? Or is there a better way?

Thanks.

Comment: Json always starts with `{` or `[`

Comment: @Eser that I know. So do we have to check if the string contains { and if it does then parse the JSon otherwise parse the other string

Comment: Check *StartsWith* not *Contains*. But yes...

Comment: Got it to work. Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

Newtonsoft.JSON or JSON.NET should be a Framework to work with(Available at nuGet) - It is able to parse JSON to Array, List or Dictionary. You can then grab the Data from Array/List/Dictionary and fill it into your POST.

[Serializing and Deserializing JSON](http://www.newtonsoft.com/json/help/html/SerializingJSON.htm)